# jquery Disabling data-scroll-speed for small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m just starting to learn JavaScript/jQuery and I am trying to disable my code for smaller screen width. The code I have  (thanks to tutorials) is changing the scrolling speed of specific  elements in my html:

```
<div id="text1" data-scroll-speed="3">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="text2" data-scroll-speed="2">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
```

Here is the code that makes it work:

```
$.fn.moveIt = function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    var instances = [];

    $(this).each(function () {
        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
    });

    window.onscroll = function () {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        instances.forEach(function (inst) {
            inst.update(scrollTop);
        });
    }
}

var moveItItem = function (el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};
moveItItem.prototype.update = function (scrollTop) {
    this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function () {
    $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

I just want this code to stop working when screen width is smaller than 770px (for example). I looked at multiple ways of how to do that and tried many, but I can’t get it right (because I’m a real newbie...).I would greatly appreciate if someone could show me a working solution. Here is an example of what I tried. Thank you and have a great day!

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt(){
        if ($(window).width() > 770) {

 $.fn.moveIt = function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    var instances = [];

    $(this).each(function () {
        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
    });

    window.onscroll = function () {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        instances.forEach(function (inst) {
            inst.update(scrollTop);
        });
    }
}var moveItItem = function (el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};
moveItItem.prototype.update = function (scrollTop) {
    this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
};
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `if` condition inside the `onscroll`

```
 window.onscroll = function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 770) {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        instances.forEach(function (inst) {
            inst.update(scrollTop);
        });
    }
 }
```

This how to append this part of code to your code

```
$.fn.moveIt = function () {
    var $window = $(window);
    var instances = [];

    $(this).each(function () {
        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
    });

    window.onscroll = function () {
      if ($(window).width() > 770) {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        instances.forEach(function (inst) {
            inst.update(scrollTop);
        });
      }
    }
}

var moveItItem = function (el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
};
moveItItem.prototype.update = function (scrollTop) {
    this.el.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -(scrollTop / this.speed) + 'px)');
};

// Initialization
$(function () {
    $('[data-scroll-speed]').moveIt();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Unfortunately, when I  do this, parallax scrolling is not working at all (neither on width bigger than 770, nor smaller). I honestly don’t have an idea why

Comment: @helplease did you change the code like the updated answer??

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. To be sure, just now I even copied your whole code and it still stops working completely

Comment: But I think it’s because I have a mistake somewhere else. I will look for it, your code looks good. Once again, thank you!

Comment: I'm really happy to hear it works .. Have a great day :-) @helplease